# Does #$P$-Completeness imply approximation hardness?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, approximation, counting

Let $\Pi$ be some counting problem which is known to be [#$P$-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete).

Does it imply that $\Pi$ is [$APX$-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APX) (i.e. no [PTAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme) for the problem exists unless $P=NP$)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Counting independent sets in graph is **#P**-hard, even for 4-regular graphs but Dror Weitz gave a PTAS for counting independent sets of $d$-regular graphs for any $d\leq5$ [3]. (In the model he writes about, counting independent sets corresponds to taking $\lambda=1$.)

Computing the permanent of a 0-1 matrix is also **#P**-hard (this is in Valiant's original **#P** paper [2]) but, relaxing your requirement a little, there's an FPRAS due to Jerrum and Sinclair [1]. This corresponds to counting perfect matchings in bipartite graphs.

**References**

[1] Mark Jerrum and Alistair Sinclair, "Approximating the permanent." *SIAM Journal on Computing*, 18(6):1149–1178, 1989. ([PDF](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0218077))

[2] Leslie Valiant, "The complexity of computing the permanent." *Theoretical Computer Science*, 8:189–201, 1979. ([PDF](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397579900446))

[3] Dror Weitz, "Counting independent sets up to the tree threshold." STOC 2006. (Unpublished full version: [PDF](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~dror/pubs/ind_from_tree.pdf).)

Answer (score 3):

Adding another example I came across, with an even stronger result:

A (deterministic) [FPTAS exists](http://web.stanford.edu/~bayati/papers/matchingptas.pdf) for the problem of counting the number of matchings in a bounded-degree bipartite graph, while this is a $\#P$-complete problem.